# QTreeView Drag and Drop: QAbstractItemView.InternalMove allows drag and drop outside view?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I'm using a QTreeView to display a custom model that derives from QAbstractItemModel.

I want to enable moving of tree items **within** the QTreeView via drag and drop and thus used `setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)` on the QTreeView. This works well for moving items around within the view, but this now also allows dragging items onto other elements, like for example all window title bars or the bookmarks bar in Firefox. Dropping items there causes the tree item to be deleted from the view.

Is that intended behavior of `QAbstractItemView.InternalMove`? The docs specify this option as `The view accepts move (not copy) operations only from itself.` ([source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#DragDropMode-enum)) which implies that dragging outside the view should not be possible to me.

Am I missing a different property here? Is it even possible to allow drag and drop only within a view? The docs are pretty vague regarding this.

Edit: Minimal, Reproducible Example with PyQt

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

model = QStandardItemModel()
model.setRowCount(10)
model.setColumnCount(1)

for i in range(0, 10):
    model.setData(model.index(i, 0), 'Row %d' % i, Qt.DisplayRole)

view = QTreeView()
view.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
view.setModel(model)
view.show()

app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: @eyllanesc question updated

Comment: What version of PyQt5 are you using, as I do not reproduce this behavior

Comment: Qt 5.15.2 on Python 3.9.1

Comment: This problem also does not come from the Python side of things as I was able to reproduce it with C++ using the same code.

Comment: I use 5.9.2, in my experience the newer versions tend to have unexpected behaviors.

Comment: I could reproduce this issue with PySide2, but it doesn't happen with PySide6.

Comment: thanks for the helpful question! I had the same problem too, and thanks to @alec's comment I managed to get rid of it by changing to a different version (5.13.2 doesn't have this issue)